# Not able to create user when executing jmeter script

Tags: jmeter

My test plan consist of http request and then parameters are passed into using REST.Even though my test executes scuccessfully and shows me confirmation page with order receipt still it is not creating user in the database.Can anyone let me what i will be doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually due to some correlation error.

From what you write , you say you see confirmation page, is it when you replay in JMeter or when you record with JMeter using your browser.

Also in title you speak about "create user" while in description you speak about "order".

Comment: there were some issues on application side which were causing that answer.Anyway thanks for taking time to answer my question.